# Clipping a responsive full width image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to clip an image which spans full width. The following things didnt work for me

1. clip: this requires position absolute so the block elements dont stack below
2. background-position: it doesnt clip properly when zoomed the clipped portion increases when zoom in and vice versa.
3. wrapper: the wrapper height is dependent on the browser width so its value should be dynamic.

I used js with setinterval 1 millisec. so that wrapper height is constantly updated. works perfect in all scenarios but setinterval is bad practice. so please suggest a cleaner way to implement this.

```
document.onreadystatechange = setInterval(function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    brow_width = document.body.clientWidth;

    var h1 = (brow_width/7);
    document.getElementById("clip1").style.opacity = "1";
    if(brow_width > 700){
    document.getElementById("clip1").style.height= h1;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("clip1").style.height= 110;
    }

    var h2 = (brow_width/33.33);    
    document.getElementById("clip2").style.opacity = "1";
    if(brow_width > 700){
    document.getElementById("clip2").style.height= h2;
    document.getElementById("banner2").style.top= h2 - brow_width*0.35;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("clip2").style.height= 21;
    document.getElementById("banner2").style.top= -220;
    }   
}
},1);
```

---

```
<!--two different clips of the same image-->
<div id="clip1">
<img id="banner1" src="banner.jpg">
</div>
<div id="clip2">
<img id="banner2" src="banner.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Just a doubt, Do you want to create a responsive banner? or specifically "clip" that banner?

Comment: @MageshKumaar i want to clip an image and the clipped portion should span full width. i am sharing my webpage url so u can have a look at what is it that i want to achieve. 

coded html: http://goo.gl/noIyWO,
template: http://goo.gl/UnXniA

Comment: Is what you're trying to clip the background image? You can specify a width of 100% and an absolute height and then set `overflow:hidden;` onto the image. I believe you could set a margin so as to get the right piece of the image to mimic the template.

Comment: @RDrazard doesnt it stretch the image if width is in % and height is absolute value?

Comment: The width and height should apply to the container of the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="bannerImg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
}

.bannerImg {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

(Also here: http://jsfiddle.net/N6mCw/)

The idea is to use the outer wrapper to crop the image. If you need to support IE<9 then instead of a background image you'll have to add an <img> tag within the inner div and remove the background-image CSS:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="bannerImg">
        <img src"…" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Although… the best way to do this would be to actually crop the image to the correct aspect ratio beforehand!

Comment: actually i want multiple cropped instances of the same image so cropping the same image multiple times would increse http requests. so i wanted it this way
thanks for the answer :)