# inline-block adds space above the first element

Tags: html, css

I have a box containing two divisions that i have to stack horizontally. Adding inline-block stack them horizontally but the first element(#ss_cont) gets a 25px top space. i checked via inspect element its neither margin or padding. so i had to use position:relative:top:-8px; what is the mistake in this?
for you to understand my problem completely i sharing links to what i am working on - 
working HTML:  http://goo.gl/EVpUum;
Template HTML: http://goo.gl/UnXniA;

```
<div id="box">
<div id="ss_cont">
    <img id="slideshow" src="slideshow.jpg">
    <div id="slid_controls">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">&#9664;</a>
    <p>Flex Engine Web Design</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">&#9654;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sep"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#box{
margin:80px auto 0px auto;
width:675px;
height:225px;
border:2px solid #dddddd;
background-color:white;
}
#box>*{margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;}
#ss_cont{
width:304px;
height:182px;
display:inline-block;
}
#sep{
height:182px;
width:0px;
border:1px solid #dddddd;
display:inline-block;
}
#slideshow{
width:300px;
height:162px;
border:2px solid #dddddd;
}
#slid_controls{
width:275px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
background-color:#888888;
}
#slid_controls *{
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
position:relative;
top:4px;
left:15px;
}
#slid_controls>p{padding:0px 45px 0px 45px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The #ss_cont container's height is set to be 20 pixels larger than the height of #slideshow image element. You should also consider increasing your box's height as well to fit the controls.

Comment: you are right but it didn't eliminate the gap completely.
i changed the #sep height to 182px from 200px still 8px gap exits.

Comment: If you mean the gap between the controls and the bottom of the box, that's just the properties of the #box container. Link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daDts/2/). On another note, I centered the slide controls' text by removing the top positioning, modifying the left, and using text-align: center.

Comment: i was speaking about the space above #ss_cont.
in jsfiddle the position is right, dunno why its not working properly in my webpage that too 8px is an arbitrary value.

Comment: Adding vertical-align:top; aligns all stack element's top portions to a horizontal line, that satisfies my requirements. but after making all the elements of equal height there should be no need of vertical-align property.

Comment: There's probably a simple CSS property mixed in there that's removed in the JSFiddle, or some external CSS messing it up.

Comment: sure i will check it out.
i donno itf its legal on stackoverflow to do this. but i want to ask it.
i have another problem, there is no answer to it yet can u please help on this one too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807023/clipping-a-responsive-full-width-image?noredirect=1#comment33000367_21807023